# Ceiling lights flash bright when switched on, but then become very dim almost immediately

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led

There are two ceiling lights in my lounge, each with three separate LED bulbs. A little while ago, I noticed that all three bulbs in one of the lights were much dimmer than usual, so tried replacing the bulbs, but this didn't seem to solve the issue. What I've noticed since, is that when I turn that light on, the bulbs initially flash to full brightness, but then become very dim - too dim to actually be at all functional. The other light seems to be absolutely fine. The bulbs I'm using are LED G9 capsules (200 lumens, 2.1 watt - equivalent to 21 watt, 220-240V).

When I first moved into the house, the lights in the lounge were what I'd describe as 'warm white' (i.e. not glaringly bright, but bright enough to light the room fully at night). When those bulbs eventually went, I replaced them with what I think may have been 400 lumen LED bulbs- though I can't remember now, I'm guessing those may have been 40 watt. I found these to be too bright, so when they went, replaced them with the 200 lumen bulbs I'm now using.

I wondered if maybe having used bulbs with a higher wattage might have damaged the the circuit in some way, and that might be why the bulbs currently there only momentarily get to full brightness - though I would have thought that if I had fused something, the lights wouldn't turn on at all...

The only other potential problem I can think of is that there is a loose connection somewhere, but again - wouldn't this make the lights either flash on/ off, or not work at all, rather than light up brightly initially before becoming very dim?

This problem is only happening with the three bulbs in one of the ceiling lights - the three bulbs in the other are lighting up to full brightness as soon as turned on, with no issues.

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I can diagnose the cause of this problem?

Comment: The size of the bulbs does not sound right, at all. Typical baseline 60W incandescent is ~ 840 lumens. First search for a G9 *LED* bulb gets 350 lumens for **4.5 W**! And that's a mediocre brand (Feit). Get to larger sizes and better quality and you can easily get to more than 100 lumens per Watt. **Forget about "equivalence"** - that just confuses things. Look up *exactly* what the bulbs are rated for in terms of power (W) and light (lumen).

Comment: "_(200 lumens, 21 watt)_" that can't be right; 21w would melt such a small bulb. "Warm white" has nothing to do with the brightness; they can be blinding or too dim and still be warm white. The new bulbs could be the wrong voltage; G9 come in 12v, 120v, and 240v lines, and using the wrong ones could result in the symptoms described. Do you have these on a dimmer?

Comment: Sounds like a bad connection on the fixture that is flashing even 75 watts is small but LED’s would be more likely to be able to produce a flash and than incandescent or cfl the drivers get enough to turn on at .5 seconds but then the driver needs more power to sustain the glow , bad connection so they barely glow. Sound similar? Look at the junction in the first light feeding the second or the connection at the second.

Comment: @dandavis Apologies, you are right - just looked at the packet again, they're 2.1 watt - equivalent to 21 watt (it says "2.1 watt equivalent to" in smaller text above the "21 watt", which I obviously had just skipped over when first reading it). The voltage is 220-240V. They're not on a dimmer. Is it likely I need a lower voltage?

Comment: @EdBeal Yes, that sounds similar, and was what I had first thought might be the case. I've had a look at the fixture, and can't see that anything is loose - did tighten up the screws a bit more just in case, but it made no difference. I guess I could try taking the fixture off completely to have a look, and then reattach it, but it seems weird that the connection would just randomly become loose with no cause - the fixture hasn't been moved/ knocked at all, etc....